# Debugging 500 Internal Server Errors

Tags: c#, sql-server, internal-server-error

Can someone tell me what are the best methods for debugging why a 500 error was thrown if it's not being stored in the logs?  I have a website written in C# and am using SQL Server Management Studio.

The problem is that a user is sometimes getting 500 errors on logging into the site.  I'm using Elmah to log errors in the database, and it usually works great, but it is not logging these errors in particular.  I know this for a fact because I know what time the error occurred, and all the logs are timestamped.

Are there any other tools I could be using if error logs aren't showing these errors?

I apologize if this question is a duplicate, but I searched lots of other posts and didn't find a match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIS has several logs. Look for a folder called HTTPErr, probably in Windows\System32\logfiles. This can contain more data.

With a 500 error, it won't ever get to your code, most likely, so there's not a lot you can do really.